# Independence of $\sigma$ algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $\{X_n\}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ are an independent sequence of random variables, why is it that $\sigma(X_1, ..., X_n)$ and $\sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2}, ...)$ are independent?  I'm trying to prove the Kolmogorov Zero One Law and this is the only part of the proof I don't understand.  Obviously each of these sigma algebras is by definition a sigma algebra generated by the union of independent sigma algebras.

Thus, $\cup_{i=1}^n \sigma(X_i)$ and $\cup_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \sigma(X_i)$ are independent sets of events.  But they are not necessarily $\pi$ systems by this post: [Union of $\sigma$-algebras is a $\pi$-system...?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042362/union-of-sigma-algebras-is-a-pi-system) (since I cannot find a way to show they are an increasing union of sigma algebras - I don't think they are).  Therefore I can't necessarily say anything about $\sigma(\cup_{i=1}^n \sigma(X_i)) = \sigma(X_1, ..., X_n)$ and $\sigma(X_{n+1},X_{n+2}, ...) = \sigma(\cup_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \sigma(X_i))$

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

Would the following be a sufficient argument?

Let $S_1 = \{A : A = \cap_{j=1}^k\{X_{i_j} \in B_j\}, i_j \in \{1,...,n \} \}$ and $S_2 = \{A : A = \cap_{j=1}^k\{X_{i_j} \in B_j\}, i_j \in \{n+1, n+2,...\} \}$

Then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are independent $\pi$ systems whose sigma algebras are thus independent (this is a separate result that is easily provable) and contain $\sigma(\cup_{i=1}^n \sigma(X_i))$ and $\sigma(\cup_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \sigma(X_i))$ respectively.  Hence the sub sigma algebras are trivially independent as they are subsets of independent collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you "just" find another $\pi$-system. Note that $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ is generated by sets of the form $(X_{j_1}\in B_1,...x_{j_k}\in B_k)$ for $(B_m)_{1\leq m\leq k}$ Borel sets and $1\leq j_1<...<j_k\leq n$, and the system of such sets *is* a $\pi$ system. Similarly, $\sigma(X_j)_{j>n}$ is generated by sets of the form $(X_{j_1}\in B_1,..., X_{j_k}\in B_k)$ again for a finite sequence of $(B_m)_{1\leq m\leq k}$ of Borel sets and $n<j_1<...<j_k$. Again this is a $\pi$ system.

Hence, fix Borel sets $(B_m)_{1\leq m\leq k}$ and $n<j_1<...j_k$ and let $(C_r)_{1\leq r\leq K}$ be any other finite sequence of Borel sets and $1\leq l_1<...<l_K\leq n$ be a finite increasing set of indices. Then, we see, by the independence assumption, that

$$
\mathbb{P}((\cap_{m=1}^k (X_{j_m}\in B_m))\cap (\cap_{r=1}^K X_{l_r}\in C_r))=\mathbb{P}(\cap_{m=1}^k (X_{j_m}\in B_m))\mathbb{P}(\cap_{r=1} (X_{l_r}\in C_r)),
$$ 
implying by Dynkin's lemma that the two measures on $\sigma((X_j)_{1\leq j\leq n})$ given by
$$
\mathbb{P}_1(A)=\mathbb{P}((\cap_{m=1}^k (X_{j_m}\in B_m))\cap A)
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{P}_2(A)=\mathbb{P}(\cap_{m=1}^k (X_{j_m}\in B_m))\mathbb{P}(A)
$$
are equal.

Since our choice of Borel sets $B_m$ and indices $j_m$ was arbitrary, this now yields, by another application of Dynkin's Lemma, that for any $A\in \sigma(X_j)_{1\leq j\leq n},$ the two measures on $\sigma(X_j)_{j>n}$ given by
$$
\mathbb{P}_3(D)=\mathbb{P}(D\cap A)
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb{P}_4(D)=\mathbb{P}(D)\mathbb{P}(A)
$$
are equal.

However, since $A$ was arbitrary, this implies that the two $\sigma$-algebras are independent.

Comment: I get everything after you state that the two generating sets are $\pi$ systems and I understand why they are $\pi$ systems.  Why are each of those sets generating sets for the sigma algebras $\sigma(\cup_{i=1}^n\sigma(X_i))$ and $\sigma(\cup_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\sigma(X_i))$ though?  My understanding of this subject is hugely flawed I know, since I feel like that is the simple part of the question.  Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: Okay. It's the same argument in both cases: Let $(Y_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ be any collection of random variables, and let's argue that $\sigma(Y_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ is generated by the collection $\mathcal{Y}:=\{\cap_{n=1}^N (Y_{\alpha_n}\in B_{n})|\;\alpha_n\in A,\; B_{n}\; \textrm{Borel}\}$. Clearly, each $Y_{\alpha}$ is $\sigma(\mathcal{Y})$ measurable by simply considering the case where $N=1$ and $\alpha_1=\alpha$. Hence, $\sigma(Y_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{Y})$. However, any element of $\mathcal{Y}$ is clearly also in $\sigma(Y_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$.

Comment: Adding these two together yields that $\sigma(Y_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}=\sigma(\mathcal{Y})$.